# PHP in_array not matching first element of the array

Tags: php

I have an array containing 10 numbers and I have setup a simple loop to check if the current value is in the array. All should match as it is comparing against the array that is from, however the first value never matches?

```
<?php
$i=0;
$numskills = sizeof($all_barristers_faves);
$all_skills_added = "Yes";

while ($i < $numskills) {

        // CHECK FOR SKILL IN FAVES
        if(in_array($all_barristers_faves[$i], $allfavourites)) {   
            echo $all_barristers_faves[$i]." Yes<br/>";
        } else {
            echo $all_barristers_faves[$i]." No<br/>";
            $all_skills_added = "No";
        }

    $i++;
}
```

This outputs: 
18 No
19 Yes
20 Yes
21 Yes
22 Yes
23 Yes
24 Yes
25 Yes
26 Yes
27 Yes
ALL SKILLS IN FAVES? No

I've tried this with various different sets of numbers and it is always the first one that doesn't match - would massively appreciate it if anyone knows the cause of this. ;-)

Comment: Please show us the array declaration!

Answer (score 0):

when I run your code like this, it returns the right values.

```
$all_barristers_faves = array(10,12,13,14);
$allfavourites = array(10,12,13,14);

$i=0;
$numskills = sizeof($all_barristers_faves);
$all_skills_added = "Yes";

while ($i < $numskills) {

        // CHECK FOR SKILL IN FAVES
        if(in_array($all_barristers_faves[$i], $allfavourites)) {   
            echo $all_barristers_faves[$i]." Yes<br/>";
        } else {
            echo $all_barristers_faves[$i]." No<br/>";
            $all_skills_added = "No";
        }

    $i++;
}
```

I would suggest for u to turn the `in_array($all_barristers_faves[$i], $allfavourites)` to `in_array($all_barristers_faves[$i], $allfavourites, false);`.
Perhaps the 18 is taken as a different type in one of the arrays. By putting the third parameter to false it does not check for same type.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code it seems that:

- You have an array with all possible values.
- You have an array with actual provided values.
- You want to know whether there are values provided that are not in the array with all possible values.

This can be done with a single line of code using the [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function which returns all items in the first array that are not present in the second array.

```
$all_skills_added = (count(array_diff($all_barristers_faves, $allfavourites)) === 0);
```

The call to array_diff gives you all items in $all_barristers_faves that do not occur in $allfavourites. When the count of these items is 0, you can be sure that all 'skills' are in 'faves'.